# How to know which users voted on a node?

Tags: 7, rating

I am using [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module and I've set it to allows only authenticated users to votes . Recently I've seen some nodes have had unusual high votes and want to investigate that. I am wondering how can I see the voters of a particular node?

Also, I'd like to know if there is any loophole that allows a user to vote more than once?

Comment: Voting API module takes care of this. There was a nice article on drupal.org to list voters in a view, but I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: @AyeshK did you find the link? ;)